# PHP upload script will not upload flash files. Why?

Tags: php, flash

I'm having trouble trying to get this upload script to work. It doesn't upload .swf, even though the script itself should work, I used a script for an image uploader and edited it so it should work with .swf files, but there seems to be a problem in PHP which doesn't allow these types of files to be uploaded.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select game (*.swf) to upload and add to the list of games:
    <input type="file" name="gameToUpload" id="gameToUpload">
    <input type="text" name="nameOfGame" id="nameOfGame">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Game" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP

```
<?php

    include('init.php');

    //Reminder to self: Turn off when finished coding!!
    error_reporting(-1);     

    //Some querys and variables used later on
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $gameFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $gameName = $_POST["nameOfGame"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `beoordelingen`.`beoordeling` (`ID`, `file`, `Spel`) VALUES (NULL, '{$target_file}', '{$gameName}')";

    //If submit is pressed
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $check = $_FILES["gameToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

        //Check if file already exists in folder
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "This game is already in the folder.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        //Check if the file type is .SWF
    if ($gameFileType != "swf") {
            echo "Sorry, only .swf is allowed for this page.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        //When any errors occured do not go passed this statement
        if ($uploadOk === 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded.";
        }
    //If no errors have occured then continue with this
    else {
        //Move the file from the temporary folder to the final destination
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            //Update the mysql database
            $conn->query($query);
        }
        //If something bad happened while trying to move the file. Show this message to the user.
        else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading the file.";
        }
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded.

Comment: The *only .swf is....* error implies that the script isn't reading the filename correctly. If you do `var_dump($_FILES["gameToUpload"])`, what do you see?

Comment: I accidently gave you the wrong error.. Sorry. It only echo's: 
 
Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded.

Comment: When I change swf to jpg, and upload a jpg image it does upload the image to my server. But change it back to swf and it fails.

Comment: Its probably because of this condition:

`if ($gameFileType != "swf") { ... }`

Comment: Can you take a look at what `$gameFileType` outputs?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan it outputs swf

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoB.Carucce Can you tell me what could be wrong with that condition ?

Comment: @Dennis1679 Lets say you're trying to upload the file _MyGame.SWF_ .
The file extension will be "SWF" and not "swf" (Remember strings are case-sensitive in php). A proper way to compare both strings, in this case would be: `if( strcasecmp($gameFileType, "swf") === 0 ) { /* Is a  swf file */ }`

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoB.Carucce Okay, that could have been a problem in the future so thanks. But in this case, the file I was uploading had a lower case extension. So it can't be the cause of my problems. I will change it though just to make sure.

Comment: @Dennis1679 $target_dir could be not a valid relative folder too... You can set it absolute with ´$target_dir = _ _DIR_ _."/uploads/";´. 
And don't forget to check if it has writing permission

P.S: (Remove the spaces in DIR constant. I couldn't remove it because of S.Overflow formatting)

Comment: @Dennis1679 According to your posted code, it's impossible to get **ONLY** the "Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded." message. So verify that. Your problem **CAN NOT** be related to `$target_dir` because that dir is used only inside the `else` statement of the `if` where the error message is fired, also if it is, normally you'll get the ""Sorry, there was an error uploading the file." message ... so try to verify what you get exactly and post it.

Comment: @akmozo I'm 100% sure that is the only message I get. I don't know why you think it can't be exactly that? Please explain to me.

Comment: @Dennis1679 The only case when you'll get that message is when the  `$uploadOk === 0` condition is true, and to get that condition true, `$uploadOk` should be `0` (for that code) which can be set when `$gameFileType != "swf"` or `$gameFileType != "swf"` and for both cases you are showing another message, that's why normally and according to that code you can not get only the "Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded." message.

Comment: @Dennis1679 A little mistake, I meant : ... which can be set when `file_exists($target_file)` or `$gameFileType != "swf"` and for both cases ...

Answer (score 1):

Hello your script is working I've tried with this [file](http://www.leconcombre.com/dl/mov1/mammyblue2.swf.zip) and is working fine. But when I change the file extension to SWF, I got this error: *"Sorry, only .swf is allowed for this page. Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded"*. You also have to check your folder permissions, and of course, **uploads** folder have to be in the same level of your php files.

Comment: Wow, it seems your file is actually the only one that I tried which actually works! I wonder why that's possible?

Comment: Can you help me figure out why some swf files will upload and some won't? I already edited php.ini to `post_max_size = 8M ` and `upload_max_filesize = 20M`

Comment: Could you post a link with the swf file you're trying to upload and you're having problems?